# Adding pin points to google map with static list of street addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a spreadsheet full of street addresses and I want to add them as pin points on a google map. Can anybody tell me if they must be converted to a geo-code to work with the google maps API?  And if so, is there a tool that will output a list of addresses in a way where I can just plug it into some javascript and have it good to go?

... Or just some tips.  I've never worked with the google maps API before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to [geocode](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) the street addresses to convert them to latitude/longitude values for your [marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) objects in Google Maps.

Since you have a static list of addresses, you probably just want to do the geocoding once, get the latitude/longitude values and associate them with the data points your have in the spreadsheet.

Once you have your data points with latitude/longitude associated, you can spin through them creating markers for each one. When you create your marker object, you specify a [google.maps.LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) object in the options:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude), 
  map: map, 
  title:"Hello World!"});
```

The map property on the options associates the new marker with the [map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) object.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free add-on for Google Spreadsheets called [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com) that makes it easy to geocode your list of addresses directly from the spreadsheet.  You can also use GeoSheets to create a customizable and embeddable map to put on your website that can automatically update with each change to the data in your spreadsheet.